# Discrepancies between Windows HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 and JNA W32Errors#HRESULT_FROM_WIN32?

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, bit-manipulation, jna

According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746(v=vs.85).aspx) a Windows ErrNo can be converted to the appropriate HRESULT via the following C macro:

```
//
// HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x) used to be a macro, however we now run it as an inline function
// to prevent double evaluation of 'x'. If you still need the macro, you can use __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x)
//
#define __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x) ((HRESULT)(x) <= 0 ? ((HRESULT)(x)) : ((HRESULT) (((x) & 0x0000FFFF) | (FACILITY_WIN32 << 16) | 0x80000000)))

#ifndef __midl
FORCEINLINE HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(unsigned long x) { 
   return (HRESULT)(x) <= 0 ? (HRESULT)(x) : (HRESULT) (((x) & 0x0000FFFF) | (FACILITY_WIN32 << 16) | 0x80000000);
}
#else
#define HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x) __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x)
#endif
```

I have checked the [JNA-Platform implementation of the same logic](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/W32Errors.java) and there seems to be a slight difference: if you look closely, you will see that **the code below actually changes the value of variable f**: `(f <<= 16)`

```
package com.sun.jna.platform.win32;

public abstract class W32Errors implements WinError {

    // ...
    short FACILITY_WIN32 = 7;
    // ...

    /**
     * Map a WIN32 error value into a HRESULT Note: This assumes that WIN32
     * errors fall in the range -32k to=32k.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            original w32 error code
     * @return the converted value
     */
    public static final HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(int x) {
        int f = FACILITY_WIN32;
        return new HRESULT(x <= 0 ? x : ((x) & 0x0000FFFF) | (f <<= 16)
            | 0x80000000);
    }
    // ...
```

**Is there anyone, who knows what the reason is for this implementation? Why cannot we simply perform** `(f << 16)` **?** I just do not get it...

Comment: Looks like a typo; `f` isn't used again after that so it will probably be optimised out anyway.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be true: I've created a small test harness to see if there is any difference between the two implementations and both of them produce the same results. Thanks. :)